# Execute External with specific buffer in vim

Tags: linux, vim

Say I have more than one buffer opened in different window.

How can I execute an external command with a specific buffer as a argument?

Say I want to execute `:!g++ "buffer no"`

How to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Your external command won't be able to do anything with a buffer number, you'll need to pass it a file name as argument. You can use `bufname()` to get the buffer name of a specific buffer:

```
:execute "!g++ " . bufname(2)
```

See `:help bufname()`.

Note that, due to different things (your `path` mainly but also your compiler's options), the buffer name may or may not be exactly what you want. You can use `fnamemodify()` to remove parts of its path or turn a relative path into an absolute one or whatever:

```
:execute "!g++ " . fnamemodify(bufname(2), ':p:h')
```

See `:help fnamemodify()` and the linked `:help filename-modifiers`.